# How do I validate child entities time periods not overlapping in EF4.2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation, repository

I have setup EF4.2 (Database First) with my MVC3 site. I have to entities fixture and fixture period. Fixture periods have start and end dates.

I need to allow customer to add/edit fixture periods in a single view in my MVC3 site.

I have this working. I also managed to validate that fixture period start/end dates are in the right order.  I did that in a partial class of the fixture period implemetimng IValidateObject. However now I need to validate that the fixture periods themselves don't overlap with each other.

How should I ensure periods don't overlap? Where should I check for this? I was going to do it at the ViewModel level (which seemed easy) however it seems a domain level concern. Should it be in the entity, repository, a service layer?

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to compare an in-memory fixture period to those in the database? Or are you trying to compare in-memory fixture periods for a particular fixture? Either way, you could use the DbContext.ValidateEntity method (called on each Modified/Added entity during SaveChanges) but how you go about that would depend on your goal.

Comment: I will be allowing them to update the entity (fixture) and the child entities (fixture periods) in one view. So I guess more need to check that what they are  about to try to update is valid in its own right. I guess I also have to worry about someone else updating the existing fixture and fixture periods at the same time but I suppose that is a separate issue. I will look at DbContext.ValidateEntity thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to create an after trigger in the database for insert and update. If the rows overlapped then I raised an error and rolled back insert. I then caught the SQL Exception on SaveChanges on Object Context and handled by adding an error to ModelState.